# Use hidden SFSafariViewController to get Safari cookies

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I was reading the following post on authenticating users from mobile web pages to native iOS 9 apps and was wondering how to best implement a hidden safari view controller similar to the hidden controller talked about below?

https://library.launchkit.io/how-ios-9-s-safari-view-controller-could-completely-change-your-app-s-onboarding-experience-2bcf2305137f#.r810oldla

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019352/ios10-sfsafariviewcontroller-not-working-when-alpha-is-set-to-0/39216788?noredirect=1#comment65951382_39216788 for updates on the latest guidelines and iOS 10 regarding this behavior

Comment: Are you really reading cookies from Safari app to inside your app? I need to read cookies from Safari app to inside my app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use this approach if you're going to distribute your app to the AppStore, because according to updated [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 5.1.1:
>
> (iv)SafariViewContoller must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller may not be hidden or obscured by other views or layers. Additionally, an app may not use SafariViewController to track users without their knowledge and consent.

Comment: As the original author of that post, I agree. It's an unfortunate but reasonable fear that someone could use a hidden safari view controller to track the user from the web to the app and back. But my making this guideline change, they've also taken away a really useful technique to make our apps work a bit more seamlessly, particularly during install.

Comment: there are a lot of questionable things like this that apps get away with. Are apps getting removed from the app store for this?

Answer (score 4):

**This has changed in iOS 11.** Going forward, every app (including Safari itself) will have a completely sandboxed data store. Official announcement [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/702/) (at the 17:28 mark).

Long live the invisible SFSafariViewController. iOS 9 to iOS 10.

If you need a way to pass a guaranteed user match through from Safari to your app, you'll need to use an existing network of device matches, such as [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). You can read about the techniques Branch uses instead of cookie passthrough [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/matching-accuracy/).

Answer (score 1):

You can give the sample code here a try: https://github.com/mackuba/SafariAutoLoginTest