# iOS10 SFSafariViewController not working when alpha is set to 0

Tags: objective-c, cookies, ios10, sfsafariviewcontroller, install-referrer

I'm using SFSafariViewController to grab user's cookie in my app. Here's is my code:

```
SFSafariViewController *safari = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:referrerUrl] entersReaderIfAvailable:NO];
    safari.delegate = self;
    safari.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    safari.view.alpha = 0.0;
    safari.view.hidden = true;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"[referrerService - StoreViewController] presenting safari VC");
    [self presentViewController:safari animated:false completion:nil];
```

This works well on iOS 9. but on iOS 10 it seems that the SF controller doesn't work (it also block my current context - which happens to be another UIWebView).

Anyone can suggest of an alternative way to hide a SFSafariViewController?

Comment: Are you grabbing user's cookies from Safari app?

Answer (score 12):

**Updated answer:**

Apple prohibits this kind of SafariViewController usage in last version of [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> SafariViewContoller must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller may not be hidden or obscured by other views or layers. Additionally, an app may not use SafariViewController to track users without their knowledge and consent.

**Old answer:**

In iOS 10 there are some additional requirements for presented `SFSafariViewController`:

1) Your view should not be hidden, so `hidden` should be set to `NO`

2) The minimum value for `alpha` is `0.05`

3) You need to add controller manually with `addChildViewController:` / `didMoveToParentViewController:` (callback's doesn't called otherwise).

4) `UIApplication.keyWindow.frame` and `SFSafariViewController.view.frame` should have non-empty intersection (in appropriate coordinate space), that means:

- safari view size should be greater than `CGSizeZero`
- you can't place safari view off the screen
- but you can hide safari view under your own view

Code example:

```
self.safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:referrerUrl];
self.safariVC.delegate = self;
self.safariVC.view.alpha = 0.05;
[self addChildViewController:self.safariVC];
self.safariVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5);
[self.view insertSubview:self.safariVC.view atIndex:0];
[self.safariVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Also, don't forget to remove `safariVC` properly after the end of the usage:

```
[self.safariVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.safariVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.safariVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Zaph0d42 nope, this knowledge comes from tests and reverse engineering.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to that. (changed the alpha to 0.05). The app is not in the AppStore yet.

Comment: @oriharel FYI: Apple prohibits this kind of SafariViewController usage in last version of [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines).

Comment: @RomanErmolov I'm using this method for install referrer purposes. following this post https://library.launchkit.io/how-ios-9-s-safari-view-controller-could-completely-change-your-app-s-onboarding-experience-2bcf2305137f#.l1petjuia. Do you know of any alternative of achieving what Google is providing as INSTALL_REFERRER for the Android SDK?

Comment: @oriharel unfortunately, I don't know another 100% way to attribution. AFAIK most of analytic systems, that provide attribution on iOS use hidden SafariVC to match click & install, when it possible. If it is impossible, they use heuristic behavior.

Comment: there are a lot of questionable things like this that apps get away with. Are apps getting removed from the app store for this?

Comment: @faceyspacey.com I don't know about concrete apps, but think that it is possible

Answer (score 2):

New info: Don't do this.
The revised App Store guidelines prohibit this practice.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

I'll leave this below for posterity:
I call the following code from my app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self checkCookie];
}

- (void)checkCookie
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domainToCheck.com"];
    SFSafariViewController *vc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
    vc.delegate = self;

    UIViewController *windowRootController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.secondWindow.rootViewController = windowRootController;
    [self.secondWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.secondWindow setAlpha:0.1];

    [windowRootController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    self.window.windowLevel = 10;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
{
    [self.secondWindow.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    self.secondWindow = nil;
    self.window.windowLevel = 0;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes this approach worked for me in the beta that I tried

Comment: what is `secondWindow`?

Comment: also what is `self.window`?

Comment: BTW this will get your app banned. See the new app review guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: self.window is the applications main window. secondWindow is the new window the you create to hide the SafariViewController

Comment: The guidelines say that the safari view controller must be visible

Comment: it's not working getting error -  Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7fb802a09190>.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this affect using invisible child view controller:

```
_safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:_requestURL];
_safariViewController.delegate = self;
_safariViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
_safariViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
[_containerViewController addChildViewController:_safariViewController];
[_containerViewController.view addSubview:_safariViewController.view];
[_safariViewController didMoveToParentViewController:_containerViewController];
_safariViewController.view.frame = CGRectZero;
```

Comment: Can you explain what is _containerViewController? In my case, 'self' is a view controller. could I use that instead? I actually tried and I get exceptions.

Comment: _containerViewController can be any VC that's currently visible. Can you tell me more about your exception?

Answer (score -1):

its possible to use  this on swift 3 for xcode 8.3.2 becausa i get all i delegate anduse correctly , but i have this error

[12:05] 
2017-04-25 12:05:03.680 pruebaslibrary[7476:136239] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: is this a question or an answer?

Comment: that was an answer?